# NetDispatcherFaultException while calling RetrieveOrganizationInfoRequest

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to invoke [RetrieveOrganizationInfoRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieveorganizationinforequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9). Problem is I can't find it in latest SDK (`Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies -Version 9.0.2.5`) - it existed in `9.0.2.4` SDK and is still supported by CRM.

There is a known way how to get around this (I mean other than downgrading SDK) - execute the request explicitly. I.E.:

```
using (var serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(org.OrganizationServiceUri),
           null, credentials, null))
{
   serviceProxy.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
   var response = os.Execute(new OrganizationRequest("RetrieveOrganizationInfo"));
}
```

This works - in a sense that CRM returns response, but client fails to deserialize it with:

> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException
>   HResult=0x80131501   Message=The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:ExecuteResult.
>   The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 1400. Element
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/9.0/Contracts:OrganizationInfo'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your
>   DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name
>   'OrganizationInfo' and namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/9.0/Contracts'.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

I guess I'm missing the type mapping somehow. I tried to replace the `DataContractResolver` with my own like

```
var contract = serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Contract;
var operation = contract.Operations.Find("Execute");
var behavior = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

behavior.DataContractResolver = new CustomDataContractResolver();
```

But the `CustomDataContractResolver` is not getting invoked. Any thoughts how to hook up on contract handling so this behavior can be overriden ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was removed by mistake and is fixed in latest Xrm Sdk.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies -Version 9.0.2.12

// using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages from assembly Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy
var response = (RetrieveOrganizationInfoResponse)os.Execute(new RetrieveOrganizationInfoRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tested the `RetrieveOrganizationInfoRequest` message a while back with an earlier v9.0 Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies NuGet package.

When I saw your question I fired up that solution and ran it. It ran fine.

Then I updated the all the NuGet packages to the latest version (except IdentityModel). This brought the CoreAssemblies package to v9.0.2.5. 
Here are the NuGet packages after updating all :

[image: NuGet Packages]

This made that message stop working, as it is no longer found in the `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages` namespace.

Though it does not appear to be documented well (or at all), the [RetrieveCurrentOrganizationRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrievecurrentorganizationrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) message may have superseded it, along with the [RetrieveCurrentOrganizationResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrievecurrentorganizationresponse?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) message.

I tested that and it works with the v9.0.2.5 core assembly.

[image: Retrieve]

Also... I typically use the request classes directly rather than instantiating OrganizationRequest with a name parameter. Your constructor example:
`new OrganizationRequest("RetrieveOrganizationInfo")`
does not seem to be a valid request name. When I used your syntax I got the same error as you.
When I tried it as:
`new OrganizationRequest("RetrieveOrganizationInfoRequest");`
I got a different error:

[image: Exception]

Also, I commend your boldness in writing your own resolver. Fortunately, getting a supported response from D365 should never be that complex.